# ReactJS - Retrieving State from Child Component

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 components, 1 parent and 1 child. I want to retrieve the state from the child and store the resulting state in an array.

Parent:

```
var arr = ['test1', 'test2'];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    <div key={i}>
      < Slider />
    </div>
}
```

Child (from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-star-rating-component):

```
class Slider extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props); 
      this.state = {
        rating: 1,
      };
      this.onStarClick = this.onStarClick.bind(this);
    }

    onStarClick(nextValue, prevValue, name) {
      this.setState({rating: nextValue});
    }
    render(){
      const { rating } = this.state;
      return(
      <div>
        <StarRatingComponent 
          name="rate1" 
          starCount={5}
          value={rating}
          onStarClick={this.onStarClick.bind(this)}
        /> 
        <br/>
      </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

I would like to retrieve each rating and store that in an array however, I am not sure how to do so. I have read you need to pass a callback function but I am unsure how to retrieve each rating for each call to Slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing much about your app, if you need to do that I would use `<StarRatingComponent />` directly in the parent component and have a `ratings` state object there (perhaps a map of name or id to rating). Alternatively, you could create a container like Slider but which handles this state (of multiple StarRatingComponents). Id do that if you're likely to reuse this in other places or if the parent is already doing other things.